# How to Change the X-Axis such that it Reflects the Data Points

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to change the x-axis so that it actually reflects what my data says and reformat it such that the ticker spacings are in increments of 20. The 'Wavelength' spans from 100-320, however on the actual graph, it is going from 0-400. I have tried the xlim function and it seemed to have just zoomed in.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure


Data_06 = pd.read_csv('/Users/....')
Data_06 = Data_06.transpose()
Data_06['Average'] = Data_06.mean(axis=1)
Data_06.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
Data_06.rename(columns={'index':'Wavelength'}, inplace=True)

Data_06_Average = Data_06['Average']
Data_06_Average.plot(x=Data_06['Wavelength'],y=Data_06['Average'])
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(10.5,5.5)
fig.savefig('test2png.png', dpi=100)


plt.ylabel('Intensity')
plt.xlabel("Wavelength (nm)")
plt.show()
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4czD.png)

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxXj2.png)

Comment: Check the correct syntax for `df.plot`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I also tried the scalex and ax.set_xticks parameters but nothing seems to be working.... I'm fairly new to Python and have been stuck on this simple task for days :( I appreciate any additional input! Thank you.

Comment: In that case check how other people use `df.plot`. No existing script uses something like `df.plot(x=df["col1"], y=df["col2"])`.